# How to know that user has rated the app on appstore or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, appirater, irate

I have downloaded the irate from this link https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate and its

running fine in my app. Can I come to know whether user actually rated the app in App Store

or not, or just opened the link? because I want to perform an action if user rate the app.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the user is outside of your app - I don't think there is much you can do to track their actions. Unless you had control over the rating systems, which you don't.

Comment: So it means it is not possible to test that the user has rated the app or not ?

Comment: Nope. You can obviously see how many users have rated your app and their ratings. However tracking a user from your app to Apples rating system is not possible. You have no control over the internal workings of Apple system and thus, as soon as the user leaves your app - that's it - no more tracking them. Unless they hit a website that you run on your own servers.

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer if it helped you. This will help others with the same question or similar.